# Will creep occur if a metal is subject to equal stress from all sides?

Tags: material-science

Aluminium creeps at a temperature range of 200 to 300 degree Celsius.
But if the entire bulk of the metal is at a uniform temperature, say, 0 degree Celsius, and no external stress of any kind is given, will creep still occur ?
Or will the creep be zero at 0 degree Celsius for aluminium?

Comment: The title and body of your question don't (currently) match.

Answer (score 1):

If a specimen of metal were subjected to hydrostatic stress it would creep indeed: the volume would change, while the "shape" would not (no deviatoric strain).
Most theories in continuum mechanics would de-couple deviatoric and hydrostatic creep behaviour, as the latter occurs often on longer timescales and is less pronounced in magnitude. In polymers the difference is such that bulk relaxation is neglected in the by far majority of the applications.

With regards to your second point, if a uniform temperature field is applied, the body will simply expand (resp. contract), no deviatoric strain, and null stresses. No creep is associated with such condition.

Comment: Thank you so much